# Regular expression for numbers in string

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2010, pattern-matching

The input string "134.45sdfsf" passed to the following statement

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(input, pattern).Success;
```

returns `true` for following patterns.

pattern = `"[0-9]+"`

pattern = `"\\d+"`

Q1) I am like, what the hell! I am specifying only digits, and not special characters or alphabets. So what is wrong with my pattern, if I were to get false returned value with the above code statement.

Q2) Once I get the right pattern to match just the digits, how do I extract all the numbers in a string? 
Lets say for now I just want to get the integers in a string in the format `"int.int^int"` (for example, `"11111.222^3333"`, In this case, I want extract the strings `"11111"`, `"222"` and `"3333"`).

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: For q2, you will have one match per string of ints

Comment: The Java `Matcher.matches()` method works as you expect, however the .Net `Match()` function returns the first _substring_ that matches your pattern, and the `Matches()` function returns "all" (though not as you _might_ expect) substrings that match your pattern. You simply need to use `^` and `$` anchors as specified in all the answers

Answer (score 3):

1. You are specifying that it contains at least one digit *anywhere*, not they are all digits. You are looking for the expression `^\d+$`. The ^ and $ denote the start and end of the string, respectively. You can read up more on that [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).
2. Use [`Regex.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split.aspx) to split by any *non*-digit strings. For example:

   ```
   string input = "123&$456";
   var isAllDigit = Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^\d+$");
   var numbers = Regex.Split(input, @"[^\d]+");
   ```

Answer (score 1):

it says that it has found it.

if you want the whole expression to be checked so :

```
^[0-9]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

Q1) Both patterns are correct.

Q2) Assuming you are looking for a number pattern "5 digits-dot-3 digits-^-4 digits" - here is what your looking for:

```
        var regex = new Regex("(?<first>[0-9]{5})\.(?<second>[0-9]{3})\^(?<third>[0-9]{4})");
        var match = regex.Match("11111.222^3333");
        Debug.Print(match.Groups["first"].ToString());
        Debug.Print(match.Groups["second"].ToString            
        Debug.Print(match.Groups["third"].ToString
```

I prefer named capture groups - they will give a more clear way to acces than